# How can Xamarin be used to wrap a web app as if it were a native app for Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Say I build a super mobile friendly web application that I want in the Play Store for Android users to be able to download.

Could I use Xamarin to:

- Wrap the entire mobile app as a single WebView
- Register for mobile push notifications

Essentially shortlining an MVP of an android app by using an existing web app?  If so, is there any well-known process or documentation that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best approach for you would be using **Xamarin Forms** with one or more pages containing only web views.
I don't love Xamarin Forms because usually for me Xamarin Android+iOS gives a better result in similar time, but your app would be so simple that doesn't make sense to do it with Xamarin Android.

Make sure that your web app will show only what makes sense to be shown in your app, otherwise you risk to see double header/footer, useless buttons... but if the website is yours adding a few parameters to change a bit the UI won't be a problem I guess.

Have a look at this example:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithWebview

Another approach is the use of Razor to build your pages in html directly inside your app, but if I understood well it's not what you need:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/

Comment: I'm only interested in using Xamarin to provide a container in which my web app will run.  I do NOT want any native components or any additional UI - simply a wrapper for the web app.  Essentially placing the web app on the Play store with push notifications enabled.  Is this possible?

Comment: Obviously it's possible, and the example shows exactly that. We used a similar approach in a project, but to give a better experience to the user we used more webviews each one showing a different page. By the way it would work also with a single one page. For the push notifications you could try to use Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is technically possible to do this as the previous answer has suggested. I would recommended firstly reviewing, the relevant stores guidelines on submissions. Apple for example will not allow a submission to their store of any application that simply mirrors the functionality of a website. I suspect Google's would likely be the same.

However that said, to answer your question, Xamarin.Forms would be appropriate for a simple application like the one you are suggesting. Or if you prefer to build to a specific OS, then in iOS with Xamarin you would use the Safari View Controller that was added in it's xcode 8.1 release. Android uses something similar as does windows.

EDIT:

You can use the Web View control in Xamarins Andorid native PCL project to encapsulate your mobile friendly website within an application here is the documentation:

[Xamarin Android Developer link to Android Web View](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/web_view/)

As for push notifications, yes this is perfectly possible using Xamarin.Android. and varies on implementation depending on what you want to use as the back end to handle them, I.E. Azure's notification hub etc.

Comment: I did something similar on Android and for Playstore guidelines are not as strict as for Appstore.

Comment: That's interesting to know. I've come across applications that do contain 'webviews' in android, but that's usually only part of the applications feature set, not the entirety of the applications functionality.

Comment: See above comment - this is for Android, and I just need a wrapper.  Nothing else.  Is this possible?

Comment: @SB2055 yep, aware of your platform choice, was simply expanding on Xamarin.Forms as an answer (It would obviously be multiplatform), but of course you could use Xamarin android natively, and use the following control: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/web_view/

I have expanded on this slightly above.

Which you could have found with a quick google.